# TFS/VSTS Git Cherry Pick API

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am wondering if somebody already used TFS/VSTS GIT Rest API to execute a cherry pick. The only documentation I have found is [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/cherry%20picks/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1) and it does not contain any example.

To me the goal of such API would be:

1. There is a commit XXX
2. I can merge it to branch BBB

But I did not manage to implement this use case.

The API apparently takes a required input parameter named **generatedRefName** (when not filling it, I get following error: "a parent reference name and target reference name is required").

Documentation states: *"Cherry pick a specific commit or commits that are associated to a pull request into a new branch."*

Would this mean that TFS API is only offering to create branch ZZZ and then cherry pick commit XXX? 
What if I only want to cherry pick XXXX in an already existing branch?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *What if I only want to cherry pick XXXX in an already existing branch?* Well one solution would be to do it with a local copy of the repo and push that change via Git not the REST API.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
Actually I am trying to avoid that:  I am looking for a solution to merge a commit to multiple branches without checking them out.

Comment: Did you just mean you want to use rest api to achieve git command ? Why you would like to do this?

Comment: Indeed, as I said earlier: "I am looking for a solution to merge a commit to multiple branches without checking them out."

VSTS API already provides capability to commit stuff on a git branch (= use the rest api to achieve git command).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a request sample to create the cherry pick via Rest API:
[image]

You can also enable the fiddler trace and then create a cherry pick from VSTS Web Portal to check the detailed request format.

The `generatedRefName` is name for a new temp branch to pick the commit. In VSTS, it does not cherry pick the commits to target branch directly. It will pick the commits to a temp branch and then you create a pull request to merge temp branch to target branch.